# How can I use Google shortening service (http://goo.gl) in Twitter for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-apps, twitter

I tried to configure Google service as custom URL shortening service by adding this url **http://goo.gl** but it's not working.

Any idea ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a wildcard to the URL to tell the application where to insert the original URL.
Your custom url should look like this:

```
http://myshortener.com/shorten?url=%@
```

However, it looks like this isn't as simple as this on goo.gl. I'll update when I find a way without any proxy-site or other things.

Comment: I tried that route, by adding it at the end of the google URL, but it's giving some error.

Comment: Yup, because Google doesn't accept the ?url=%@ argument. I haven't found a way to use it.